# Array en hola mundo

Tags: java, array

Tengo dos clases, una Main "salida" y otra "contenedor"
En la clase Main mando a llamar la clase "contenedor" obteniendo así un "Hola mundo" más cualquier dato que el usuario ingresé

Mi duda es, donde podría meter un Array en el código? Y que función podría ponerle a dicho Array

Clase "Salida"
public class Salida {

```
public static void Main(String[] 
args){

contenedor llamada=new 
contenedor();

llamada.metodo1();
}
```

}

Clase "contenedor"
importa java.util.scanner;

```
public class contenedor{
public void metodo1(){
 Scanner read = new 
 Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("ingresa un 
saludo");
String saludo = read.next();
System.out.println("Hola mundo " + 
saludo);
  }
}
```

Comment: Pues que intentas representar con la clase 'Contenedor'? Un objeto en programación es en sí una abstracción de un objeto de la vida real, tangible o abstracto... contenedor de que es? de autos? de juguetes? de cualquier cosa?

Comment: Intento representar como si fuera un saludo que escribe el usuario y se va guardando los diferentes que vaya escribiendo

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a arrays primitivos (que no son de la clase Collections como ArrayList o LinkedList) entonces podes hacer asi:

Clase Contenedor (los nombres de clases van con mayusculas):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contenedor {

  private String[] saludos; // array de saludos
  private int arraypointer; // apuntador del indice de saludos

  public Contenedor(){ // funcion constructora
    this.arraypointer = 0;
    saludos = new String[30]; // los arrays primitivos tienen un tamaño fijo y hay que aclararlo
  }

  public void getSaludos(){ // metodo que imprime los saludos
    for( int i=0;i<arraypointer; i++){
      System.out.println(saludos[i]);
    }
  }
  
  public void metodo1(){
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("ingresa un saludo");
    String saludo = read.next();
    saludos[this.arraypointer] = saludo; // guardamos el saludo
    arraypointer++; // incrementamos el apuntador
    System.out.println("Hola mundo " + saludo);
  }
}
```

Despues en el main:

```
public class Main { 
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Contenedor mycontainer = new Contenedor();
    mycontainer.metodo1();
    mycontainer.metodo1();
    mycontainer.metodo1();
    mycontainer.getSaludos(); // imprime los saludos
  }
}
```